# How come Te Ka intercepted Maui in the middle of the ocean?

Tags: moana

Te Fiti becomes Te Ka shortly after her heart is removed by Maui. He flies away from the island, and eventually encounters Te Ka.

How did Te Ka intercept Maui in the middle of the ocean? We learn that Te Ka can't touch the water.

Comment: My instinct is that she *erupted* from under the ocean.

Comment: When Moana reached the island it can be seen that there is ... for lack of the better words let's go with "empty spot". SO I'd say Maui woke Te Ka and did not skedaddled in time to avoid The Slap. Not to mention that Te Ka has substantial reach.

Comment: it's also worth mentioning that we only see this interaction as part of Grandmother's storytelling, which at this point may as well be ancient mythology.  Remember that in her story, Maui was very much the villain, and the flashback we see certainly portrays him as such as well.  It's entirely possible the "real" story didn't happen the way Grandmother narrated it.

Answer (score 2):

This was addressed in [*The Art of Moana*](http://conceptartworld.com/books/the-art-of-moana/). In short, Te Ka can travel a reasonable distance from the central island **under the ground**, emerging from beneath the water.

This is sufficient for her to eventually form a *ring of islands* some distance from the central island.

[image]

As you can see, Maui is escaping from the main island when he's accosted at almost exactly the same point that Moana is blocked from entering the ring of islands protecting the central mound.